Is there a way to take a swagger file and generate like WSDL document
I have a Swagger (OpenAPI) specification file for my REST API, and I need to generate a WSDL document from it. The goal is to provide a WSDL document for clients that expect SOAP services. I understand that Swagger is used for RESTful APIs while WSDL is used for SOAP, but is there a tool or a method that can help convert a Swagger file into a WSDL document?
Has anyone encountered this issue before and found a solution? Any guidance or recommendations on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.
I have searched online for tools or libraries that could facilitate this conversion but haven't found any straightforward solutions. I tried using some generic API transformation tools, but they seem to focus on converting between different REST API specifications rather than from REST to SOAP.
Additionally, I attempted to write a Python script to manually map the Swagger definitions to WSDL, but it didn't add much value and proved to be more complex and time-consuming than anticipated.
I expected to find a tool or script that could directly take my Swagger file and generate a corresponding WSDL document, preserving as much of the API's structure and functionality as possible. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to achieve this, and most solutions seem to require manual intervention or complex workarounds.
Has anyone successfully managed this conversion, or is there a recommended approach or set of tools for achieving this?

See if these Q&As help: Creating a SOAP wrapper to an existing REST web service, Write a wrapper to expose existing REST APIs as SOAP web services?
